# Using type trait to ensure a type cannot be derived from itself

Tags: c++, type-traits

I would like to statically check if a class is derived from a base class but not from itself. Below is an example of what I try to achieve. The code compiles unfortunately (never thought I would say this).

I was hoping for the second static assertion to kick in and see that I tried to derive a class from itself. I would appreciate if you guys could help me in understanding better what I am doing wrong. I tried to search online without success.

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Base {};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : T {
  static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value, "Type must derive from Base");
  static_assert(!(std::is_base_of<Derived, T>::value),
                "Type must not derive from Derived");
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Derived<Base> d__base; // should be OK
  Derived<Derived<Base>> d_d_base; // should be KO

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good news: you have nothing to do. A C++ class cannot be derived from itself. The reason your code compiles is because none of the classes in the shown code derive from themselves!

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure about this or maybe I do not understand. The `Derived` class is templated and derives from the parameter. This example is minimal, so it might look contrived.

Comment: There's no such thing called "templated class" in C++. You either have a template, or a class, which can be an instance of some template. `Derived` is not a class. It is a template. A template is not a class. A class is not a template. The shown code has exactly three classes: `Base`, `Derived<Base>` and `Derived<Derived<Base>>`. None of them derive from themselves.

Comment: Also note that `d__base` is a reserved identifier because it contains two consecutive underscores. User code is not allowed to declare this identifier or define it as a macro in any context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Type must not derive from Derived

`Derived` is not a type in itself, it's a template which in `std::is_base_of<Derived, T>::value` gets resolved to the current specialization in the context it's in and it can never be `T`. If you have `Derived<Derived<Base>>` then `T` is `Derived<Base>` and the `Derived` without specified template parameters is `Derived<Derived<Base>>`, so, not the same as `T`.

You could add a type trait to check if `T` is `Derived<something>`:

```cpp
template <template<class...> class F, class T>
struct is_from_template {
    static std::false_type test(...);

    template <class... U>
    static std::true_type test(const F<U...>&);

    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};
```

Now, using that would prevent the type `Derived<Derived<Base>>`:

```cpp
struct Base {};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : T {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value,
                  "Type must derive from Base");
    static_assert(!is_from_template<Derived, T>::value,
                  "Type must not derive from Derived<>");
};

int main() {
    Derived<Base> d_base;                // OK
    // Derived<Derived<Base>> d_d_base;  // error
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That is an excellent answer. Concise, wich a solution, and very well explained